# C++ convert string with word and number to number

Tags: c++

How to convert string like `3 word 12 with word` to a int only contain number `312` without using `stoi` in `C++`? My Codeblode gave me an error `stoi is not a member of std` when I tried to use it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use `-std=c++14` compiler switch, and update the compiler to [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org) (the default one it comes with is crap)

Answer (score 1):

Go through the line and skip non-digit symbols. And for digits use `-'0'` conversion and `*10` shift approach. E.G.:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//or cctype to use isdigit()
#include <string.h>
//or cstring to use strlen()

int main()
{
    char str[] = "3 word 12 with word"; // can be any string
    int result = 0; // to store resulting number
    // begin of solution
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            result *= 10;
            result += str[i] - int('0');
        }
    }
    // end of solution
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as in [VolAnd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734070/4833). Just, because the question is tagged `c++`, using some STL stuff.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::string input("3 word 12 with word");

    int num = std::accumulate(input.begin(), input.end(), 0,
            [](int val, const char elem) {
                if (isdigit(elem)) {
                    val = val*10 + (elem-'0');
                }
                return val;
        }
    );

    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

note: It gets slightly more interesting if you want to allow a leading minus sign....

And using [boost::adaptors::filter(rng, pred)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) on this one would be fun but slightly overdoing it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `s` is your initial string.

```
int toInt(string s) {
    string digits;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            digits.push_back(s[i]);

    int res = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++)
        res = res * 10 + digits[i] - '0';
    return res;
}
```

Leading zeros are not a problem.
Note however that it is possible to receive an overflow if the resulting `digits` string will contain a big number.